# EditText and Reflection

Tags: java, android

My problem is a little particular.

I show forth in code:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {


    public HashMap initEditText(Context context){
        HashMap list = new HashMap();
        Field[] fields = context.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field : fields){
            if(field.getName().startsWith("e_")){
                String word = field.getName().substring(2);
                String firsCaract = word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
                String key = field.getName().substring(3);
                try{
                    Class<?> cl = field.getType();
                    // To get the value of the member in the object: (object is an instance of MyClass)
                    //Object o = field.get(c);

                    if (EditText.class.isAssignableFrom(cl)) {
                        EditText value = (EditText) field.get(context);
                        list.put(firsCaract + key, value.getText().toString());
                    }

                }
                catch (IllegalAccessException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

        return list;
    }
}`
```

This class, MyActivity, serve me as mother class

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class TestActivity extends MyActivity {
    public EditText e_prenom = null;
    private EditText e_nom = null;

    private TextView t_prenom = null;
    private TextView t_nom = null;

    private Button validate = null;

    private TextView display = null;

    private HashMap list;

    String text2 = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testt);

        e_prenom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_register_prenom);
        e_nom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_register_nom);

        t_prenom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_register_prenom);
        t_nom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_register_nom);

        validate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.valider_register);

        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.affiche);

        list = new HashMap();

        e_prenom.setText("Du Con");
        e_nom.setText("Du Puis");


        list = initEditText(this);
        Iterator it = liste.keySet().iterator();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        while(it.hasNext()){
            Object key = it.next();
            Object value = liste.get(key);
            builder.append(String.valueOf(key) + "_" + String.valueOf(value) + "\n");
        }

        text2 = builder.toString();

        validate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                display.setText(text2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

TestActivity, the child class that inherits MyActivity.

In MyActivity initEditText is a method that allows to recover all fields starting with "e_" (those are more precisely the EditText) and storing their names and values in a HashMap.

In TestActvity, I have two EditText "e_prenom" and "e_nom". By calling initEditText I stock value in a HashMap I then traveled and clicking on "validate" the content of this HahMap ("list") is displayed in a TextView ("display").

So I expect to have as result the textView "Prenom_Du Con" "Nom_Du Puis".

But only "Prenom_Du Con" is displayed.

anybody know why ?

After several investigations and tests I noticed that this line

```
Field[] fields = context.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
```

All my fields are recovered

But here

```
if (EditText.class.isAssignableFrom(cl)) {
                    EditText value = (EditText) field.get(context);
                    list.put(firsCaract + key, value.getText().toString());
                }
```

Only one of the fields (EditText) has its value retrieved.

Is there a property of View (EditText accurate in this case) that I do not know and which is the cause ?
This comes from a property of Field.get (Object object)?

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve? what is your goal?

Comment: For the app I'm working on, there are many EditText and several treatments will be done above. To save time and code, I want to recover the contents of all these EditText in a list. I will send this list to another class that will make treating

Comment: so add all of your `EditText`s to some container like `ArrayList` or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your problem is to do with your modifiers (public,private...):

```
public EditText e_prenom = null;
private EditText e_nom = null;
```

As you can see one is public, and the other is private.

To access the private field, you make it accessible:

```
field.setAccessible(true);
```

So overall, it'll look like:

```
public HashMap initEditText(Context context){
    HashMap list = new HashMap();
    Field[] fields = context.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : fields){
        field.setAccessible(true); //Add this line here
        if(field.getName().startsWith("e_")){
            String word = field.getName().substring(2);
            String firsCaract = word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
```